# Angle change under orthogonal projection

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry, vector-analysis

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, consider a line segment $[AB]$ and a line $l$
containing $C$. Then we have angle $\angle ACB$ at $C$. We want to
find an angle smaller than it.

Assume that ${\rm area}\ \Delta ABC'$ is smallest s.t. $C'\in l$,
where $\Delta xyz$ is a triangle with vertices $x,\ y,\ z$ and ${\rm
area}$ is a area function. Then

> $\angle AC'B \leq \angle ACB$.

Is this right ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the presence of "orthogonal projection" in your title. Do you mean that the areas such as ABC or ABC' are the projected areas on the Oxy plane ? Same question about angles: is it the angles of vertical projections ?

Comment: I post my answer. $C$ is orthogonally projected into $C'$ wrt line $l$

Comment: It is hard to understand for me. As C is already on line $\ell$, when you say "C' is orthogonaly projected with respect to $\ell$, but on projected on what ? Could you explain the meaning of "with respect to"

Comment: I mean : For example if a triangle $ABC'$ is in $xy$-plane and $l =\{ (0,0,t)\} + C'$, then $C\rightarrow C'$ is a projection

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1** : $ {\rm dim}\ {\rm conv}\ [AB]\cup l =3 $

Note that there is a plane $P$ containing $\Delta ABC'$ s.t. $P$ is
perpendicular to $l$.

Let $$t:=|C-C'|,\ f(t)=\angle ACB,\ |B-C|=a,\ |A-C|=b,\ |A-B|=c$$ By
Cosine Law
$$
  a^2+b^2+2t^2 -2\sqrt{a^2+t^2}\sqrt{b^2+t^2}\cos\ f=c^2 $$

So \begin{align*} & 0<f<\pi,\ -\sin\ ff' \\& \\&=   \frac{d}{dt}
\frac{c^2-a^2-b^2-2t^2}{-2
 \sqrt{a^2+t^2}\sqrt{b^2+t^2} }
    \\&\\&= \frac{t \{ -(a^2-b^2)^2 + (a^2+b^2+2t^2)c^2 \} }{4 (
    \sqrt{a^2+t^2}\sqrt{b^2+t^2})^2}
\end{align*}

Hence if $a=b$, then $f'(t)<0$ for all $t$.

By considering $a=b+c$ we have $f'(t) >0$ for $0<t<\epsilon$ if $a$
is close to $b+c$.

**Case 2** : $ {\rm dim}\ {\rm conv}\ [AB]\cup l =2 $

If $l'$ is a line containing $[AB]$ and if $l'$ intersects $l$, then
$\angle AC'B=0$

If $l'$ is parallel to $l$, then $C'$ is not uniquely determined.

Consider $A=(0,0),\ B=(\varepsilon, 0),\ C=(x,1)$ Let $f(x)=\angle
ACB$. Then by Cosine Law
$$ x^2+1+(x-\varepsilon)^2 +1 -2\sqrt{x^2+1}\sqrt{ (x-
\varepsilon)^2 +1} \cos\ f=\varepsilon^2 $$

$$ -\sin\ ff' = \frac{ -\varepsilon^2(\varepsilon-2x)   }{ (\sqrt{
x^2+1}\sqrt{ (x- \varepsilon)^2 +1} )^3 } $$

Hence $f'(x)<0$ for $x> \frac{\varepsilon }{2}$.